# Bluetooth but not WiFi works on Broadcom 43142A0

Tags: broadcom

On Ubuntu 17.10, I have the Broadcom 43142A0 (`0a5c:216c`), and I have tried everything I have found on Broadcom that I can. I have no Internet on that machine. I download files on my Windows laptop and transfer files over.

I got the Bluetooth working using one of the solved solutions I found on here, but I can't seem to get the wireless working.

From what I've read, it seems I have a rarity among the Broadcom chipsets.

I'm new to Linux, so please explain like you were talking to a five year old.

The `lspci -nn` line for my network card:

```
01:00.0 network controller [0280]: broadcom limited bcm43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
```

Comment: Open Terminal, type command `lspci -nn` that lists your hardware, edit this question and add the line with your wireless card here so it's easier to help.

Comment: I ediited like you ask, and thats the first time ive seen 14e4:4365.

Answer (score 0):

There's two driver setups for Broadcom Wifi, `bcmwl-kernel-source` and `firmware-b43-installer`. Some chips work with the former, some work with the latter. Don't have them both installed at the same time.

You need to install `bcmwl-kernel-source` for your chip according to [this page](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers). You can install it with Terminal command `sudo apt install bcmwl-kernel-source`. Some chips also work better if IPv6 is set to "Ignore" in Wireless properties.

You can download the .debs for 17.10 from here: https://packages.ubuntu.com/artful/bcmwl-kernel-source

Install it by running `sudo dpkg -i bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu3_amd64.deb`. You may also have to download and install its dependencies.

Comment: Do you have any links for installing that with out an internet connection.  All the ones i find are for older versions. And it seems that 17.10 has a bug that gives errors when trying to install .deb manually. Sorry the all the trouble.

Comment: @jwade I added offline installation instructions.

Comment: The linux-libc-dev dependence cant be downloaded. It pulls up 404 not found.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I used a friends lap top and connected it through bluetooth pan. Everything is working for now.